# How to provide security for inter-servicee communication in Microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I am working on `Spring Boot Microservices` project, asking one doubts mainly from the security perspective between inter-service communication. In my project we've API Gateway which screen all incoming requests for security issues before routing them to the appropriate microservices. The API gateway sits between the client applications and the microservices. It then limits exposing the microservices while providing additional request management functions such as authentication, SSL termination, protocol translation, monitoring, request routing, caching, and more.

Assume Case Microservice1(MS1) >> Microservice2(MS2) >> Microservice3(MS3), since the authentication and Authorizations are happening at API GW layer, then how can we provide security to interservice communication? What if someone directly calls MS2 or MS2 endpoints directly?

Dept answer is anticipated here.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the authorization in the API GW the token it produces should have all the permissions that the user has and you should propagate that token through the various calls.

Comment: Thanks, How can we identify the MS1 token is not getting used in MS2 etc, how will you make sure to have single Tx calling multiple microservices?

Comment: if each service validates the token (e.g. by the public key of the issuer) then they can 1. trust the claims, 2. make sure that there is a signed token on the call. You can intercept the calls in a handler (details are per technology) and do that once in each service